# Proving $\frac{\sqrt{a+b+ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c+bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a+ca}}{\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt{b}}\ge 3$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c+2\sqrt{abc}=1.$ Prove that$$\frac{\sqrt{a+b+ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c+bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a+ca}}{\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt{b}}\ge 3.$$

I've tried to use AM-GM as
$$\frac{\sqrt{a+b+ab}}{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{c}}+\frac{\sqrt{b+c+bc}}{\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{c+a+ca}}{\sqrt{ca}+\sqrt{b}}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{(a+b+ab)(b+c+bc)(c+a+ca)}}{\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{c}\right)\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}\right)}}.$$But $$\frac{\sqrt{(a+b+ab)(b+c+bc)(c+a+ca)}}{\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{c}\right)\left(\sqrt{ac}+\sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}\right)}\ge 1,$$is not true when $c=0; a=b=1/2.$

I hope you find a appropriate approach. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try substituting $a=x^2, b=y^2$ and $c=z^2$.

Comment: Yes, but I can not find better idea.